# Is there a universal medical terms naming convention web resource?

Tags: terminology, health-informatics

I want to use proper conventional names for known diseases and cell and tissue types in my scientific research. Is there a web resource where I can look the terms up and make reference to this resource?

Comment: Other relevant terminologies are: - SNOMED-CT - Foundational Model of Anatomy

Comment: what is the point of replying when my answers get deleted. How exatly  I did not answer the question?

Comment: @userJT I've told you repeatedly that answers require supporting references. That's been established policy here since 2015. To understand why read [this meta question](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) and the top voted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Health insurances and hospitals (for the coding of the diseases) often use the **International Classification of Diseases** (ICD) from the **World Health Organisation** to standardise the naming of the diseases and assigns them a code.

There is an *online available version* (ICD-10) here:

http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2016/en

For the classification of tissues and cells, you might maybe find an answer on the biology SE.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the source. I ended up using this one and MeSH term dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The following are naming conventions that satisfy your question:

- SNOMED-CT
- Foundational Model of Anatomy
- ICD (current version 10, it has national modifications (such as USA's ICD-10CM)

Comment: Provide a supporting reference or this answer will be deleted.